# How to add programmatically Images into resources?

Tags: c#, resources

I have some image files in my resouces [.resx file] that I have added by using Visual Studio. But, now I need to add the Images programmatically into resource.

How do I this?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? I can't think of any practical scenario... You can always load images from files directly at runtime.

Comment: It is possible (although maybe not the best technique) to work on a Resources.resx file as an XML document. stackoverflow.com/a/43431478/253938

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `ResXResourceWriter.AddResource` method for each resource you want to add to the resx file. Use the *overloads* of this method to add string, object, `and binary (byte array) data`. If the resource is an object, it must be serializable.

See here for a complete sample - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx